# Assigning a relative value to elements in a string array to generate an array of integers

Tags: c++, arrays, string, algorithm, integer

I have the following string array:

```
string userValuesStringStArr[7] = { "Karen", "Tom", "Bob", "Wendy", "Alan", "Ellen", "Kelly" };
```

I would like to do the following:

1. Search the entire string and compare all the elements alphabetically.
2. Based off of those comparisons, create an integer array with their relative values it.

| Karen | Tom | Bob | Wendy | Alan | Ellen | Kelly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | 6 | 2 | 7 | 1 | 3 | 5 |

The int array should now look like this:

```
int arrOrder[7];
```

The `arrOrder` values should be: `4 6 2 7 1 3 5`

3. Finally, create a string variable with the values `"4, 6, 2, 7, 1, 3, 5"` in it.

The idea is that, if I were to switch any of the names at the beginning, it should generate a different integer array, and matching string variable.

For example:

```
//pre-inserted string in source code

string userValuesStringStArr[7] = { "Karen", "Zoe", "Bob", "Wendy", "Alan", "Ellen", "Kelly" };

//processing happens here

//output

int arrOrder[7]; //4 7 2 6 1 3 5

string arrOrder; //"4, 7, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5"  //the commas and spacing are really important
```

I know that using c-strings and vectors could help with this problem, but I really need the string array, int array, and string variable to have this format.

I tried using the string compare and assign their relative values that way, but I get stuck in figuring out an algorithm where all string as compared to each other and create integer values.

```
string userValuesStringStArr[7] = { "Karen", "Tom", "Bob", "Wendy", "Alan", "Ellen", "Kelly" };

int orderStrings[7];
        
for (int count = 0; count < 7; count++)
{
            
    if (userValuesStringStArr[count] < userValuesStringStArr[count + 1])
    {
        orderStrings[count + 1] = count + 1;            
    }
    else
    {
        orderStrings[count] = count + 1;               
    }
}
```